# 'Free worldwide shipping' vs 'Free shipping worldwide' vs 'Free shipping to worldwide'

Tags: meaning

'Free worldwide shipping' vs 'Free shipping worldwide' vs

'Free shipping to worldwide' vs 'Free shipping globally'

I'm curious what expression is correct to use , and if there is different meaning

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please add a few thoughts of your own - did you do some research? We are glad to help, but hesitant to do the work for you.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for reply! Yeah I tried to search and found Free worldwide shipping have most search result number on google but can't find different meaning or correct word

Comment: "Free worldwide shipping" sounds more natural to me than "Free shipping worldwide"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out yourself, the *usual phrase* is:

- "free worldwide shipping"
  its basically aequivalent to:
- "free shipping worldwide"

You *can't* use:

- "free shipping to worldwide"
  because "shipping to" requires a certain place given as a *noun*. You can ship to an address, a city, even a continent. You could ship to the moon, if the postal service would fly there. But "worldwide" is an *adjective*, and therefore not usable.

You *shouldn't* use:

- "free shipping globally"
  because the term "globally" does mean "concerning/relating to the entire world", and has a more abstract/metaphorical meaning than the term "worldwide" ("everywhere/every place in the world"). You would say "my company is operating globally", but you would say "we have offices worldwide".

Answer (score 2):

"Free shipping to worldwide" doesn't quite flow: it sort of makes sense, but "to" implies a singular destination which "worldwide" doesn't fit with.

The other three correct and would be understood to mean the exact same thing.

"Free worldwide shipping" sounds perhaps most natural, but I really don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: I would say "to worldwide" doesn't work because worldwide is an adjective not a noun (or destination).